# Неправильно считает логарифм

Tags: c, математика

Столкнулся с проблемой во время решения логарифма. После вычисления результата выводит 1,87 (Что является ошибкой). Нужный результат 0,81.В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int  main()
{
    float x,y,d=2.5;
    scanf("%f",&x);
    scanf("%f",&y);
    float t1 = log(y*x+d);
    printf("%f\n",t1);

}
```

```
Input: 2 2
Output: 1.87
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`log` - это **натуральный** логарифм, по основанию 2.718281828459045....

Используйте функцию `log10`.